# Constraint violation when trying to set "User Cannot Change Password" in active directory from c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've tried multiple ways to set the flag "User cannot change password" in active directory from c#.

The following haven't worked:

- Setting "CannotChangePassword" to true on the user principle object
- Setting access rules on the user object security on the directory entry (http://urslisworld.blogspot.ca/2010/02/set-user-cannot-change-password-in-c.html)
- Directly setting the ntSecurityDescriptor (http://sourcefield.blogspot.ca/2009/12/cactivedirectory-check-user-cannot.html)
- and of course, I can't directly set the user account control property according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144

The first three each give the exact same, highly cryptic error message, "Constraint Violation" with the extended message:

```
0000051B: AtrErr: DSID-030F20BA, #1:
0: 0000051B: DSID-030F20BA, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 20119 (nTSecurityDescriptor)
```

Here is the simplest case code that should have worked (option 1):

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, myDomain, myAccountOperatorUsername, myAccountOperatorPassword))
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userNameToChange))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.UserCannotChangePassword = true;

            user.Save()
        }
    }
}
```

The powershell way of doing this works perfectly fine, using the same credentials from the same machine. In fact, it works so well I can automate it in the code and it succeeds:

```
using (var PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Import-Module Active-Directory");
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString \"" + myAccountOperatorPassword + "\" -AsPlainText -Force");
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist \"" + myAccountOperatorUsername + "\", $password");
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Set-ADAccountControl -Identity " + usernameToChange + " -CannotChangePassword $true -Credential $cred");

    var PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

}
```

However the powershell way makes the deployment more complicated for something that should be accomplishable in pure c#.

Is this a problem with the domain, the environment the code is running in, or the code itself?

Comment: I copy and pasted your C# code into a console application, substituted values and it ran without any problems. My guess would be that there is something about the users which means the flag shouldn't be set. Are they expired, or do they have "User must change password at next logon" enabled?

Comment: @Ashigore I tried with a variety of users with no success. None of the users have any special flags, they are all enabled and their password is not expired (or have the flag "User must change password at next login"). I don't know enough about Active Directory to understand which constraint is being violated, or how to identify that - or why the powershell method has the ability to change the flag.

Comment: I assume your account or whichever account is running the C# code has permissions to change the users in AD?

Comment: @Ashigore I've tried two different account operator users, these users can change the flag from PowerShell and the snap-in "Users and computers", but not from the code.

Comment: Hopefully you see this, @Resorath ... I'm having a somewhat similar problem and was wondering if this was ever solved?  If you don't mind having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025191/what-permissions-do-i-have-to-delegate-in-order-to-set-usercannotchangepassword I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem using a very similar C# code. In my case, the account we were using to set the "User cannot change password" flag had that option marked itself. When we removed the flag from the account, the code started working.

This is something that, apparently, only affected C#. Other implementations of the solution worked fine, including PowerShell.